# Memory leak when opening Excel - resulting in a crash

Tags: excel, vba

I have a matrix with i.e dimensions 300x300 (x & y,size vary from project to project).
The names/numbers of the individual rows are transposed to the columns.
The matrix is divided diagonally, and I use it to tag relations between different "systems".
The tag have to be a unique number. See image:

[image: Matrix example]

I do not want duplicated relations, so I just want to use the white cells to add the tag.
(The black ones are there to show that the system cant have a relation with itself.)

I have tried to make a range, that I apply a Validation to later which shows me the next number in line for the tag:

```
Public MatrixRange as Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim n As Integer
Dim NextRange As Range
Dim OldRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

With shMatrix
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Set MatrixRange = .Range("C11")
    If LastRow <= 1 Then Exit Sub 
    
    For n = 2 To .Range(.Range("A9").Offset(1, 0).Address, "A" & LastRow).Rows.Count
        Set OldRange = MatrixRange
        Set NextRange = .Range(.Range("B9").Offset(n, 1), .Range("B9").Offset(n, -1 + n))
        Set MatrixRange = Union(OldRange, NextRange)
        
    Next n
End With

End Sub
```

This code give me the correct range that I want, but it sometimes hogs a whole lot of memory when I open the workbook or try to save. The RAM just goes up and up when I start it, before the workbook just crashes without any error message.
Rewriting the code to select the whole matrix, not just the one half, seems to fix the issue.

My question is this: is it possible to rewrite the code so I get the correct range, with a different method or are there any flaws in my code that will create a memory leak?

I call the above sub also when applying the Validation, if MatrixRange is not created:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ValMax As Integer

If MatrixRange Is Nothing Then
    Call CreateMatrixRange
End If

ValMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(MatrixRange)

With MatrixRange.Validation

    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:=ValMax + 1
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = False
    .InputTitle = "Next number"
    .ErrorTitle = "Error"
    .InputMessage = ValMax + 1
    .ErrorMessage = "Next number is: " & ValMax + 1
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
    
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: "I have tried to make a range" But what are you doing with the created range? That is a bit unclear...

Comment: I add the Validation to the range, Max number used + 1

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private prMatrix As Range
'* plLastRow is used to check if the matrix range changes after it had been set
Private plLastRow As Long

Private Function GetMatrixRange() As Range
    Dim lStartCol As Long: lStartCol = 3
    Dim lStartRow As Long: lStartRow = 11
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    With shMatrix
        lLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If lLastRow < lStartRow Then lLastRow = lStartRow
        
        If prMatrix Is Nothing Or lLastRow <> plLastRow Then
            plLastRow = lLastRow
            Set prMatrix = .Cells(lStartRow, lStartCol)
            
            '* Row Number -> Number of Columns mapping
            '* Row 11 -> 1 column
            '* Row 12 -> 2 columns
            '* Row 13 -> 3 columns , ...etc
            '* Therefore, Number Of Columns = Row Number - lStartRow + 1
            For i = lStartRow + 1 To lLastRow
                Set prMatrix = Union(prMatrix, .Cells(i, lStartCol).Resize(1, i - lStartRow + 1))
            Next i
        End If
    End With
    
    Set GetMatrixRange = prMatrix
End Function

Private Function GetNextValue() As Long
    GetNextValue = WorksheetFunction.Max(GetMatrixRange) + 1
End Function

'Private Sub SetValidation()
'    Dim lNextValue As Long
'    lNextValue = GetNextValue
'
'    With GetMatrixRange.Validation
'        .Delete
'        .Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, _
'             AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
'             Operator:=xlEqual, _
'             Formula1:=lNextValue
'        .IgnoreBlank = True
'        .InCellDropdown = False
'        .InputTitle = "Next number"
'        .ErrorTitle = "Error"
'        .InputMessage = lNextValue
'        .ErrorMessage = "Next number is: " & lNextValue
'        .ShowInput = True
'        .ShowError = True
'    End With
'End Sub
'
'Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'    SetValidation
'End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, GetMatrixRange) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = Empty Then Target.Value = GetNextValue
        Cancel = True
    End If
ErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim rWatched As Range: Set rWatched = Intersect(Target, GetMatrixRange)
    Dim lNextValue As Long
    Dim lEnteredValue As Long
    
    
    If Not rWatched Is Nothing Then
        Target.Select
        If rWatched.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            rWatched.ClearContents
            MsgBox "You cannot change more than 1 matrix cell at a time"
        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(rWatched.Value) Then
            rWatched.ClearContents
            MsgBox "Only numeric values allowed"
        Else
            If rWatched.Value <> Empty Then
                lEnteredValue = rWatched.Value
                rWatched.ClearContents
                lNextValue = GetNextValue
                If lEnteredValue <> lNextValue Then
                    If MsgBox("The next allowed value is: " & lNextValue & ". Do you want to accept it?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                        rWatched.Value = lNextValue
                    End If
                Else
                    rWatched.Value = lEnteredValue
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

ErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I replaced the validation code with double-click and change event handlers. Feel free to remove these handlers and uncomment the validation and selection change code if you need to.

This code will do the following:

- If you change any cell in the matrix, it will validate it and give
  you the choice to accept the allowed value. Otherwise, it will delete
  what you had entered.
- If you double-click a cell in the matrix, it will be populated with the next value